# Amazon MQ cost details

Tags: amazon-web-services, activemq-classic

I am trying out the new Amazon MQ service. So far I have been using the "mq.t2.micro" instance type, and I want see how much cost is incurred for this service.

I have been trying to figure it out, looked at the AWS Cost Explorer, but couldn't find any cost related stuff for Amazon MQ.

Kindly guide me on how to find details cost breakdown for Amazon MQ.

Comment: Have a look at the link : https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/pricing/

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the following URL http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

Comment: This is an estimator for the cost, and not a real cost calculator. Moreover, it does not even provides an estimate for Amazon MQ service

Answer (score 0):

Billing is based on instance-hours and message storage, plus charges Internet data transfer if the broker is accessed from outside of AWS - from https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-mq-managed-message-broker-service-for-activemq/

So price would be based on t2.micro + storage used and that can be calculated using AWS resources calculator

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did went through the blog post already. I am running a broker on mq.t2.micro instance. To my understanding there is a t2.micro instance managed by AWS itself, therefore it won't show up in the EC2 instances in my account and so in the Cost Explorer I see nothing under the EC2 instance hours spent for Amazon MQ